# Django mod_wsgi Apache error 403 Forbidden on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: permissions, python, apache2, 22.04, django

Django mod_wsgi on Apache application works fine in Ubuntu 20.04 and previous versions with the configuration mentioned below, but when I do the same configuration in Ubuntu 22.04 it gets 403 Forbidden error. and Permission denied: mod_wsgi in the error log.

I tried changing permission on all files it's doesn't work,

Apache config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        <Directory /home/ubuntu/mydjango/mydjango>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>

        alias /static /home/ubuntu/mydjango/static
        <Directory /home/ubuntu/mydjango/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        WSGIDaemonProcess myapp python-home=/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv python-path=/home/ubuntu/mydjango
        WSGIProcessGroup myapp
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/ubuntu/mydjango/mydjango/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache Error Log:

```
Current thread 0x00007fb606719780 (most recent call first):
  <no Python frame>
[Sun Jun 05 05:59:07.594727 2022] [wsgi:warn] [pid 37044:tid 140419768883072] (13)Permission denied: mod_wsgi (pid=37044): Unable to stat Python home /home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv. Python interpreter may not be able to be initialized correctly. Verify the supplied path and access permissions for whole of the path.
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = 'python3'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.base_prefix = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/usr/bin/python3'
  sys.prefix = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv'
  sys.path = [
    '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv/lib/python310.zip',
    '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv/lib/python3.10',
    '/home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
```

Comment: Your issue is self-explanatory.  You need to install the `encodings` module in your venv.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I can't find the ```encodings`` module in pip , can you tell me the package name in pip

Comment: Based on my research, `encodings` is already part of Python;s core libraries, including Python 3.10.  It might be because your `PYTHONPATH` is not s3et in your application but I'm not sure.  There's a lot of chaos that comes with Django and venvs, and that could be a source of the problem.  How'd you create your Django venv?  (it suggests that you don't have a complete venv for Python where you have venv)

Comment: I created venv with ```python3 -m venv /home/ubuntu/mydjango/venv``` with this command on a fresh install of ubuntu 22,
But this error not came on ubuntu 20 with the same setup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72505153/django-mod-wsgi-apache-error-403-forbidden-on-ubuntu-22-04

I found a solution the, it's a permission error need to give permission to home directory